# Pandas xlsx comparing dates and if equal then give the right col

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, xlsx

I have a xlsx like this.

```
            date   value   ...      
0     2021-07-31  244793   ...        
1     2021-08-01  244685   ...   
2     2021-08-02  453193   ... 
3     2021-08-03  453258   ...
```

I want to check and compare the date from today with the date in the xlxs.
When the date today and the date in the xlsx is == i want to get the value behind the date.
Like today is 2021-07-31 so i get the value 244793.

This is my code.

```
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

date_today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

df = pandas.read_excel('example.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet')

a = df[df['date'] == date_today]

print(a)
```

I dont know how to complete my idea and i dont find the right tools i need.
Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: To me it looks like your code already does what you're asking? It creates a new dataframe of all of the values that are equal to the current date. The only thing left in my mind is to print(a['value']) or print(a.loc[0,'value']), but please correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Yes its almost what i want, maybe i didn´t made my self clear. Also i´m not a native speaker. 
So, now that a give me the right row i need. How can i display only the value and not the index and date?

Comment: I would think this would work: print(a.loc[0,'value']), but be aware that this only selects the first row (=0) in a. (So if you have multiple rows in the dataframe that match the current date, only the first value of these will be printed, so you would have to loop through the dataframe.)

Comment: Perfect, this is what i was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think this would work:

```
print(a.loc[0,'value'])
```

But be aware that this only selects the first row (=0) in a. (So if you have multiple rows in the dataframe that match the current date, only the first value of these will be printed, so you would have to loop through the dataframe.)